# Regex search CSS to find if class exists AND contains rule

Tags: css, regex, visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of CSS files: I'm trying to find ALL instances of the class `.aligncenter` that contains the rule `display: block;`. I don't care in what order the rule appears, just whether or not that class exists and whether that rule exists inside the class.

Here's what I tried:

`/.aligncenter \{([\d\D].*display: block;[\d\D].*?)\}/gs`

But this yields mixed results.

I'd also like for the search to work in Visual Studio Code's file search if possible, I've had pretty mixed results with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try;

`\.aligncenter[-:;,.!#%$"()>\s\w]*?\{[-\\:;,.!#%$+*"'/()\s\w]*display:\s*block[-\\:;,.!#%$"+*'/()\s\w]*\}`

see [regexr](https://regexr.com/5el36).

Hopefully I got all the special characters that can appear in a `css` file.  If not, just add them to the three groups of special characters in the regex.

Also beware in the `content: '►';` almost any character could appear.

Answer (score 0):

Trying it out on RegExr ([link](https://regexr.com/5eku4)) with different possible cases, this seemed to do the trick:

```
/\.aligncenter[^{]*\{[^}]*(display: block|display:block|display: block;|display:block;)+[^}]*\}/g
```

Matches the following cases:

```
.aligncenter {display:block}
.aligncenter {display:block;}
.aligncenter{display:block}
.aligncenter {margin: 0; padding: auto; display:block;text-align:center;}
.yetanother, .aligncenter, .anotherclass {margin: 0; padding: auto; display:block;text-align:center;}
.aligncenter {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display:block;
  flex: 1 0;
}
.aligncenter {
    display: block;
}
```

#### Update

To get the same results in VS Code than in RegExr, we must replace the first set inside the properties to properly capture in non-minified css, like so (**updated to fix bug mentioned in comments**):

```
\.aligncenter[^{]*\{([^}]|\w\s\S)*(display: block|display:block|display: block;|display:block;)+[^}]*\}
```

That seems to work accordingly:

[image: Results of RegEx search on VS Code]

Comment: Try `.aligncenter { <anything but display:block here>}` in your regexr.  It is captured  - because `(display: block;*)*` doesn't require that `display: block` actually exists.

Comment: @Mark oooof, embarrasing to have missed that, I've updated it to fix it